# Using CSS to create a vertical stack of thumbnails

Tags: css, html

I am trying to create a vertical stack of image thumbnails.  One thumbnail per line.

I am trying to upgrade my CSS skills.  I have this working with a table using

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td><img /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><img /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td><img /></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I'd like to not use a table and accomplish this using divs and CSS.  This was I have better control over the spacing and layout in the future.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple:

```
<div><img /></div>
<div><img /></div>
<div><img /></div>
```

A div is a block level element.  Unless you specified other wise it acts similarly to a `<tr>` tag

Comment: I know this.  :(  I'm trying to be too fancy with CSS and missed the basics.  Thanks.

Comment: Alternately, you could have just specified `img { display: block }` and left out the `div`s.

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple div and put some id's for every img. In CSS for the same you can modify the properties of the different id.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you start by learning about DIVs and their properties.  [W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_div.asp) is a good start.

To get started with yours simply do:

```
<div>
   <img src="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="" />
</div>
<div>
    <img src="" />
</div>
```

DIVs by default are treated as `block` elements meaning they start on a new line automatically.  So if you want them to appear inline then you will need to specify that by either using `display: inline-block;` or `float:left`;

Answer (score 0):

Use divs/sections, define how many columns you want, lets say 4 columns...

http://jsfiddle.net/tBDjV/

```
<div class="col-1">
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
<div class="col-2">
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
<div class="col-3">
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>
<div class="col-4 last">
    <img />
    <img />
    <img />
</div>

.col-1, .col-2, .col-3, .col-4 {
float: left;
width: 22%;
margin-right: 4%;
box-sizing: border-box;
}

.last {
margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: He only wants one thumbnail per line.  This solution is over complicated for what is needed.

Comment: This is actually more along the lines of what I am looking for and helps a lot.  I know I didn't ask for this level of complexity, but I am trying to learn how to use DIVs instead of tables so it's valuable to me.